# Where are Azure Storage Explorer configurations stored?

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage-explorer

On MacOS, I'm trying to restore Microsoft Azure File Explorer settings/configurations from an old hard drive backup. I'd like to get all the previous account connections back without having to set them up again manually. Where is this data stored in the MacOS directory structure so I can copy it to the new hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's doable as of today but this is definitely a much-requested feature:

- [Feature request : backup file #754](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/754)
- [Export Settings (include Quick Access) #2880](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/2880)
- [Persisting the Transfer and such Explorer settings at machine level. #4169](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/4169)

Feel free to comment on any/all of the above issues adding more context or [create a new issue](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/new/choose) for the Storage Explorer Team to evaluate and prioritize.